# How to get inner element in xml file by using python

Tags: python, xml

I have next xml :

```
<a>
  <aa id = 1>
    <data>aaaa</data>
  </aa>
  <aa id = 2>
    <data>bbbb</data>
  </aa>
  <aa id = 3>
    <data>cccc</data>
  </aa>
</a>
```

I would like to reach the data's text (aaaa,bbbb...)
How can I do it ? (I've been using etree.ElementTree package)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: tree = xml.parse(file)
toot = tree.getroot()
listElem = root.findall("aa")
for elem in listElem:
          STUCK FROM HERE

Answer (score 1):

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <aa id="1">
    <data>aaaa</data>
   </aa>
   <aa id="2">
    <data>bbbb</data>
  </aa>
  <aa id="3">
    <data>cccc</data>
  </aa>
</a>
```

You can use an `XPath` query:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = etree.parse('/tmp/a.xml')

xml.xpath('.//data/text()')
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'] #returns that
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the etree package

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2]: tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

In [3]: root = tree.getroot()

In [4]: for el in root:
   ...:     print el.find('data').text
   ...:     
   ...:     
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

The only thing that you are missing from the code you provided is `elem.find('data').text` (inside of your `for` loop`) - that will return the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
tree = xml.parse(file) 
root = tree.getroot() 
listElem = root.findall("aa") 
for elem in listElem:
     tmp1 = elem.findall("data")
     str = tmp1[0].text
```